# Column sumup calculations and rows avg count

Tags: excel, vba

Problem 1.
I do have a table with multiple columns in it. The number of columns and rows might change from table to table. I do manage, with help of humble people from this forum, create a function to find a cell I need, where formula must be inserted. But I'm struggling with formula, because as I said, the number of rows might be different from table to table, and position of the columns change all the time.

Here is an example. As you can see I have certain columns, but I only need to sum up variables form column `need` and `need2`. There are might be more `need3...5` columns on the table.

[image: example picture]

Problem 2
Beside column sum-up function, I also need to insert formula for each row on the table into last two columns `avg min` and `avg max`. The problem is that number of columns might change and I only need to consider specific cells on a row to proceed with the calculation `=average(need;need2)` and there are might be more than only two **needs** that must be considered.

Below is my solution that choose correct cell but I'm really struggle with formula that might do the trick.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, clmone As Range, clmA As Range, txt, intrng As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set intrng = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each clmone In ws.Range("1:1", ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
    txt = clmone.Text
    If InStr(1, txt, "need", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, txt, "need2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        For Each clmA In intrng.Cells
        If StrComp(LCase$("total"), "total", vbTextCompare) Then
        ws.Cells(clmA.Row, clmone.Column).Select 'should be formula instead of select
        Else: End If
    Next clmA
    End If
Next clmone
```

Comment: Using the data from the screenshot, what would the formulas in `G2` and `H2` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If a text (txt) meets the condtion `InStr(1, txt, "need2", vbTextCompare) > 0`, then `InStr(1, txt, "need", vbTextCompare) > 0` must return `True`. Reverse is not correct. Keeping the second condtion is sufficient.
- `ws.Range("1:1", ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))` is equalient to `ws.Range("1:1")` no matter how many cells are used. It should be corrected to `ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))`.
- There is only ONE `total` cell in the table. The loop to locate total cell should be done before `For Each clmone`. Using `Find` is more efficient to locate the cell. Both apporaches work well for a small table.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Col As Range, intRng As Range, txt
    Dim cTotal As Range, headerRng As Range, targetRng As Range
    Dim lastCol As Range
    Const KEYWORD = "need"
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set intRng = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set cTotal = intRng.Find("total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    Set lastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    Set headerRng = ws.Range("A1", lastCol)
    For Each Col In headerRng
        txt = Col.Text
        If InStr(1, txt, KEYWORD, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If targetRng Is Nothing Then
                Set targetRng = Col
            Else
                Set targetRng = Application.Union(targetRng, Col)
            End If
            If Not cTotal Is Nothing Then
                Cells(cTotal.Row, Col.Column).Formula = "=SUM(" & Cells(2, Col.Column).Resize(cTotal.Row - 2).Address & ")"
            End If
        End If
    Next Col
    If Not targetRng Is Nothing Then
        ' Create and populate last two columns
        '        lastCol.Offset(0, 1) = "avg min"
        '        lastCol.Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=MIN(" & targetRng.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
        '        lastCol.Offset(1, 1).AutoFill Destination:=lastCol.Offset(1, 1).Resize(cTotal.Row - 2), Type:=xlFillDefault
        '        lastCol.Offset(0, 2) = "avg max"
        '        lastCol.Offset(1, 2).Formula = "=MAX(" & targetRng.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
        '        lastCol.Offset(1, 2).AutoFill Destination:=lastCol.Offset(1, 2).Resize(cTotal.Row - 2), Type:=xlFillDefault
        ' the last two columns (header) are exists
        txt = targetRng.Offset(1).Address(0, 0)
        For Each Col In lastCol.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 2)
            With Col.Offset(1).Resize(cTotal.Row - 2)
                If VBA.StrComp(Trim(Col.Value), "avg min", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    .Formula = "=MIN(" & txt & ")"
                ElseIf VBA.StrComp(Trim(Col.Value), "avg max", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    .Formula = "=MAX(" & txt & ")"
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Application.Union method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: thank you very much for your time. I spent some time before i realise certain solutions you've used in your answer. Everything worked just as it suppose to work for total calculations, but for the last avg columns I see that you went further and made function to create those columns. I'm very sorry to bother you even more, but may be you can push me a bit into direction how to better locate cell i need, because i guess i understand logic behind the formula, but cannot see solution to properly locate the destination cell.

Comment: What the expected result for last two columns? What's the different `avg min` vs `avg max`? You can change its formula w/ `lastHCell.Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=MIN(" & targetRng.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & ")"`.

Comment: The results are correct. My issue is that those columns pre-exist in my document, and i just need to fulfil them not create.

Comment: Are the name always `avg min` and `avg max`? Or are the last two columns?

Comment: Yeah, names are const.

Comment: And i just checked formula for last columns. Its not particularly right.  Im sorry for time waste, i was checking and understanding first part of the function, application method is very elegant i must say. But for the avg row, the values must be taken from "need" columns only, other columns should be ignored.

Comment: May I know what's the desired formula, `min/max or average`? I don't think the parameter of formula is incorrect. Please check the screenshot. Updated code to pupolate the last 2 columns instead of creating.

Comment: I'm dumb, I did certain manipulations and didn't even notice that and there for it takes extra sells into calculation. So far, all works like charm. Last question, the rest i will try to figure out my self, is there a way to compare exact text value of a cell with desired parameter? Like if i have "need2need" but my desire parameter is "need2"?

Comment: To compare exact text: case sensitive `If CellValue = KEYWORD Then`,   
ignore case sensitive `If LCase(CellValue) = LCase(KEYWORD) Then`

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Using VBA

[image]

```vb
Sub CalculateData()
    
    Const CRITERIA_STRING As String = "need"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim hrg As Range, drg As Range, trg As Range
    
    With rg.Resize(, rg.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1)
        Set hrg = .Rows(1)
        Set drg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2).Offset(1)
        Set trg = .Rows(.Rows.Count)
    End With
    
    Dim hcell As Range, c As Long, hAddress As String
    
    For Each hcell In hrg.Cells
        c = c + 1
        If InStr(1, CStr(hcell.Value), CRITERIA_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            hAddress = hAddress & drg.Cells(1, c).Address(0, 0) & ","
        End If
    Next hcell
    
    If Len(hAddress) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No ""Need"" columns found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    hAddress = Left(hAddress, Len(hAddress) - 1)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With drg.Columns(drg.Columns.Count)
        .Offset(, -1).Formula = "=MIN(" & hAddress & ")"
        .Formula = "=MAX(" & hAddress & ")"
    End With
            
    trg.Formula = "=SUM(" & drg.Columns(1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data calculations populated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some fix on your code. StrComp() returns 0 if the strings are equal. You may get idea how to tweak other avg functions from below ** sum formula.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, clmone As Range, clmA As Range, txt As String, intrng As Range
Dim firstCell As String, lastCell As String
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set intrng = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

For Each clmone In ws.Range("1:1", ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
    txt = clmone.Text
    If InStr(1, txt, "need", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, txt, "need2", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        For Each clmA In intrng.Cells
            'StrComp() returns 0 if the strings are equal.
            If StrComp(LCase$(clmA), "total", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                firstCell = ws.Cells(intrng.Row, clmone.Column).Address
                lastCell = ws.Cells(intrng.Row + intrng.Rows.Count - 2, clmone.Column).Address
               ' ** sum Formula
                ws.Cells(clmA.Row, clmone.Column).Formula = "=SUM(" & firstCell & ":" & lastCell & ")"
            End If
        Next clmA
    End If
Next clmone
```

Comment: thank you very much for correcting StrComp function. Also I appreciate your help with sum formula, but cannot understand the logic how to locate all required cells for row calculation of avg value with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the layout of your data is always as shown in your posted picture, i.e.:

- data starting from cell A1
- columns headers in the first row
- rows headers in the first column
- "total" row as the last one and empty
- "avg min" and "avg max" columns as the last two ones and empty

then you can go simply:

```
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, 1).Offset(1, .Columns.Count - 2).FormulaR1C1 = "= MINIFS(RC2:RC[-1],R1C2:R1C[-1],""need*"")"
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, 1).Offset(1, .Columns.Count - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "= MAXIFS(RC2:RC[-2],R1C2:R1C[-2],""need*"")"

    .Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 3).Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(R1C,4)=""need"",SUM(R2C:R[-1]C),"""")"

End With
```